# How do I use cgroups in fstab instead of default /sys/fs/cgroup from systemd?

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab, cgroups

I want to mount my cgroups from fstab instead of allowing systemd to mount them at /sys/fs/cgroup. I have my fstab written with targets such as /cgroup/cpu, /cgroup/blkio.. etc. When I boot up, the machine boots into emergency mode and I see messages such as:

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /cgroup/cpu.
See 'systemctl status cgroup-cpu.mount' for details.
```

Checking the status reports:

```
mount: /cgroup/cpu: cgroup already mounted on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd.
```

So it looks like systemd is racing to mount its own cgroups before it mounts the ones I want in fstab.

Is there any way to get systemd to yield to my cgroups in fstab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I have learned that systemd refuses to budge on where it mounts these. [This page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/) outlines which mounts can be prevented from automatically being mounted and which cant. The list specifies that `/sys/fs/cgroup` is always mounted automatically.